# How to work with String Array?

Tags: android

This my might be a stupid question, but how do you work with String Array?

I am trying to do something like this, but my app would crash upon launching.

```
String names [] = null ; 

    names[0]= "I am";
    names[1]= "Ammar";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), names[1] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: can you post logcat ?

Comment: You must be getting **NullPointerException**

Comment: you need to define string length before start working with it 
you are getting null pointer exception or Either Array out of bound Exception becasue your array size is zero and you are trying to access the 0+nth index that is not defined in Array so causing your app to get Crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
String names [] = null ;
```

with

```
String names[] = new String[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the array, just like any other array

```
String names[] = new String[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

you should define array size.

`String name[] = new String[2];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
String[] names = new String[2];

names[0] = "I am";
names[1]= "Ammar";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), names[1] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

may be you are getting error because you have not allocated memory to string array. You have assigned null to the array that's why the application is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] names = { "I am", "Ammar" };
```

Answer (score 1):

Array follows the concept of static allocation of memory so you must define how much memory or size you need before using it.

`String[] names = new String[10];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard issue with Object Instantiation. If you're going to define a reference, you must either point it to an already existing object **OR** create a new reference to the object using the `new` keyword.

Ex:

```
[Class] x = new [Class]()
```

Where `[Class]` is the object you're wanting to instantiate/use.

Whenever an object reference is created and is not instantiated, that object **will** be initialized to null.

Ex:

```
[Class] x;
```

after this line, x will be null since it does not have a valid object reference (new or not).